# Convert integer time facebook message time - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to Covert This time to date time like " 08:45 PM "

json time code

```
{"time":1480797244,"short":false,"forceseconds":false}
```

i need covert this time (1480797244) need idea in jQuery or javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below method to convert the timestamp to your required format. Check the [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tb50y9u6/1/) also

```
function formatAMPM(timestamp) {

  date = new Date(timestamp * 1000)
  var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var day = date.getDate();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' +  hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

var timeObj = {"time":1480797244,"short":false,"forceseconds":false};
alert(formatAMPM(timeObj.time))
```

Comment: i need add month and day and year , how i can do it ?

Comment: @Abdo-Host Updated the fiddle. Please check now